# Data Mining, PyFim.eclat

Tags: data-mining

Why the PYFIM.eclat module in python giving less number of frequent itemsets? Actually, I given database with 8 length frequent itemsets but fim.eclat(db) giving output for only 4 length itemsets.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code sample

Answer (score 0):

Probably because there are **no frequent** patterns of length 5?